# Convert StartIndex/EndIndex to PageNumber/PageSize

Tags: algorithm, optimization, indexing

I'm currently struggling with a problem that appears quite easy to resolve at first glance, and should be a very common requirement, but it turns out to be a surprisingly complex task, and it's hard to find any information/solutions online.

The situation:

- We are displaying items (that we request page-wise from a server / REST API) in an on-demand list view. Whenever the list view is scrolled, it requests a new range of items to be displayed (defined by a `startIndex` and an `endIndex`, both 0-based).
- The API for requesting paged items from the server expects a 1-based `pageNumber` and a `pageSize` (a very common API design).

The problem is how to convert the `startIndex`/`endIndex` to an *integer* `pageNumber` and `pageSize` that returns *at least* the requested range of items (it is obvious that not *every* range of start/end index can be mapped to an exact page number/size, so we typically have to request a *larger* range of items than we actually need, by either decreasing `startIndex`, increasing `endIndex`, or both).

**Example 1**: The list view requests to display items 2..7 (6 items), so our request page size is 6. However, requesting page 1 with a size of 6 will return only items 0..5. Requesting page 2 with a size of 6 will return items 6..11. None of these cover the requested range of 2..7, so it follows that we need to extend the page size, and load *more* items than needed (which is fine, as long as the  the page size remains within reasonable limits, and all requested items are included). The optimal solution in this case would be to request page 1 with a size of 7 (decrease `startIndex` by 1).

**Example 2**: The list view requests to display items 121..128 (8 items), so our request page size is 8. However, requesting page 16 with a size of 8 will return only items 120..127. A possible (perhaps not the optimal) solution in this case would be to request page 13 with a size of 10, which gives us items 120..129 (range covered).

Simple enough?

The reverse calculation is trivial: Given a page number and page size, the resulting range of returned items is easy to determine:

```
• startIndex = (pageNumber - 1) * pageSize
• endIndex = pageNumber * pageSize - 1
```

The challenge is to invert these 2 equations, and calculate `pageNumber` and `pageSize` from a given `startindex` and `endIndex`.

All our attempts so far have led to a system of 2 equations with 2 unknowns, and the need to optimize 2 variables (`startIndex` and `endIndex`) with the following constraints:

```
• startIndex <= startIndex0 // We may include more items at the beginning of the range, never less
• endIndex >= endIndex0 // We may include more items at the end of the range, never less 
• minimize for endIndex - startIndex // We want the requested range to be as small as possible.
```

To me, this reeks of a non-linear optimization problem (twisting two variables to minimize for a value), but there might also be a much simpler, algorithmic approach. It feels like a grade 11 calculus problem, but I'm shockingly rusty in that area.

I had initially expected to find an easy, common solution to this problem by Google-fu, since APIs that expect a `pageNumber`/`pageSize` are very common, and UIs/ListViews requesting a range of items by `startIndex`/`endIndex` should be too.

I'm happy and grateful for any ideas to solve this, either mathematically (preferred) or at least algorithmically.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is algorithm based, not mathematic, and might not be as efficient as you need. But i think it is at least a good idea you might keep working on.

First of all what we need to minimize is only `pageSize`, once you have a `pageSize` you can determinate how many extra items you will have (a simple minus operation will do it) and what is the pageNumber if any that will allow you to cover all the items.

So we can go through all the posible `pageSize` from `endIndex - startIndex` to `endIndex`, keeping in mind that the first `pageSize` that is able to cover all items with a calculated `pageNumber` will be the one that asks for less extra items.

I'll leave a python code function here that will do the work.

```
def index_to_pages(startIndex, endIndex):
    startIndex += 1  # 0 based to 1 based
    endIndex += 1    # 0 based to 1 based
    totalItems = endIndex - startIndex + 1   # If both are included
    for pageSize in range(totalItems, endIndex + 1):    # at least totalItems, at most endIndex items
        if (startIndex - 1) // pageSize != (endIndex - 1) // pageSize:    # if it cannot cover all items, then we keep going
            continue
        return ((startIndex - 1) // pageSize) + 1, pageSize  # returns pageNumber, pageSize
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your solution works great, and is actually very efficient (the loop terminates quickly) => Minimal page sizes.


Goes to show that I was totally overthinking the problem, and looking for a mathematical solution where your simple iterative approach works perfectly well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think calculus is going to help you much with all the step functions involved.  But here is a JS implementation that I believe does the trick.

```js
const pagination = (startIndex, endIndex) => {
  let pageSize = endIndex - startIndex, pageNumber = 1
  while (pageNumber * pageSize <= endIndex) {
    pageSize += 1
    pageNumber = Math .floor (startIndex / pageSize) + 1
  }
  return {pageNumber, pageSize}
};

[
  [0, 4],       //=> {pageNumber: 1, pageSize: 5}
  [1, 5],       //=> {pageNumber: 1, pageSize: 6}
  [10, 15],     //=> {pageNumber: 2, pageSize: 8}
  [121, 128],   //=> {pageNumber: 13, pageSize: 10}
  [125, 133],   //=> {pageNumber: 9, pageSize: 15}
  [140, 172],   //=> {pageNumber: 5, pageSize: 35}
  [3264, 3280], //=> {pageNumber: 193, pageSize: 17}
  [3260, 3279], //=> {pageNumber: 164, pageSize: 20}
].forEach (([s, e], _, __, {pageNumber: pn, pageSize: ps} = pagination(s, e)) =>  
    console .log (`pagination (${s}, ${e}) //=> {pageNumber: ${pn}, pageSize: ${ps}}`)
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We simply test increasing page sizes until we find one that covers our range.  It's not elegant, but it's fairly simple.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Scott! You're right, I was overthinking the problem, a simple iterative approach is more than enough (see Daniel's solution).

I tried yours first, and it looked good at first glance (very efficient, minimal page sizes), unfortunately, it's not 100% correct: There are still certain value pairs where it fails to load the last requested item (example: startIndex = 3264, endIndex = 3280 => pageNumber = 164, pageSize = 20 => requested Items: 3260..3279).

Comment: Hmm, I get a different result (the same one Daniel's returns) for `3264 - 3280`, which is `{pageNumber: 193, pageSize: 17}`, and that's clearly minimal as our range has 17 elements.  And it has the same result for `3260 - 3279`,  (`164/20`).  I added these test case to the snippet.  I'm still curious if there's a mathematical formula that captures this, though.  I won't spend the time digging to figure it out, but if you run across one, please post!

Comment: You're right, my bad... The problem was with my implementation/testing of your suggestion. It works just fine, thanks again! I have marked your reply as answer, too. Thanks so much again.

Comment: Glad you like it.  But Daniel posted a very similar algorithm and beat me by over an hour. 
 I would choose his, unless you simply want to choose JS over Python.  Also, I just noticed that there was a simplification available, and I updated to include it.

Comment: Looking at this again after my change, I think there has been a bug at the boundary.  I updated the code again, added some more test cases, and note that  `121 - 128` should yield `13/10`, as the previous answer `16/8` won't capture index `128`.   Converting zero-based to one-based indices, especially with both boundaries inclusive, can cause headaches!

Answer (score -1):

- The API is inefficient and should be changed.
- When a row is inserted or deleted, the scrolling will screw up -- this leads to a bad User interface.
- What is done with the items are different sizes?  That is, is the number of 'items per page' really a constant?

What to do instead?

- Have a unique id on each row
- Ask for the N rows starting with (or ending with, if going backward) a specified id.
- The server deals with optimizing the lookup.
- Exactly N rows are returned.  Or N+1 are returned -- thereby providing an indication that there are no more rows (when < N+1 are returned).

OK, you really want to live within the "pagination" world.  Row number DIV N to get page number.  Adjust the "page number" by 1.  Then ask for 2 pages.  Optionally, you could check to see if it is exactly on a page boundary; that is whether MOD N = 0.